# How do I alter the anchor point of an overlay div in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, overlay

I am quite new to using JS so please forgive me on any ignorance I may have. I have searched and played around with the script but so far no luck and was hoping to find help here. What I have is a table with 4 columns in it that is holding images. When I hover over the images, a transparent overlay slides from the bottom to the top, and when I exit the hover, it slides back down, and becomes completely hidden once more.

Here is a JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/g6xVR/99/

What I am looking for, is the overlay to remain visible by about 30px, so instead of being anchored to the very bottom of a div, it would calculate the anchor point 30px above the bottom.

Here is the code I am using. I pulled it from javascriptkit. http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/divcontentoverlay.shtml

```
    jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery.extend(jQuery.easing, {easeOutExpo:function (x, t, b, c, d) { 
        return (t==d) ? b+c : c * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * t/d) + 1) + b;
    }
});

(function($){
  $.fn.overlaycontent=function(options) {  
    var setting={id:'', dir:'up', speed:200, opacity:1}
    return this.each(function(){
      $.extend(setting, options, (this.getAttribute('data-overlayid'))? {id:this.getAttribute('data-overlayid')} : {})
            var $target=$(this).css({position:'relative', overflow:'hidden'})
            var $overlay=$('#'+(setting.id))
            var startpoint={}
            if (setting.dir=="up" || setting.dir=="down"){
                startpoint={top:$target.outerHeight() * (setting.dir=="down"? -1 : 1)}
            }
            else{
                startpoint={left:$target.outerWidth()* (setting.dir=="right"? -1 : 1)}
            }
            var overlaydimenions={w:$target.outerWidth()-($overlay.outerWidth()-$overlay.width()), h:$target.outerHeight()-($overlay.outerHeight()-$overlay.height())}
            $overlay.css($.extend({position:'absolute', zIndex:'1000', width:overlaydimenions.w, height:overlaydimenions.h, left:0, top:20, visibility:'visible'}, startpoint)).appendTo($target)
            if (setting.opacity<1)
                $overlay.css({opacity:setting.opacity})
            $target.hover(
                function(){
                    $overlay.dequeue().animate((setting.dir=="up" || setting.dir=="down")? {top:0} : {left:0}, setting.speed, 'easeOutExpo')
                },
                function(){
                    $overlay.dequeue().animate(startpoint, setting.speed)
                }
            ) 
    })
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I discovered how to alter the startpoint. Taking the outer height of the target and then subtracting from that, anchoring it in the position I wanted.

```
if (setting.dir=="up" || setting.dir=="down"){
                startpoint={top:$target.outerHeight() - 30 * (setting.dir=="down"? -1 : 1)}
            }
```

The finished result. http://jsfiddle.net/g6xVR/100/